# Is it possible to specify the number of threads used by cbc in bonmin options?

Tags: python, coin-or-cbc, casadi

I'm trying to solve a MINLP using bonmn. However, due to the large scale of the problem to be solved, the computation time is very long. It seems that the MILP part is taking a long time, so I would like to speed up the CBC solver used in MILP by specifying options such as the number of threads. However, it seems that the only cbc options that can be specified from bonmin are the ones written in the middle of the page below (those that can be specified with Cbc_Par).

https://www.coin-or.org/Bonmin/options_set.html

Is it possible to specify the number of threads used in cbc from bonmin? Also, if there is another way to speed it up, please let me know.

I tried most of the options related to bonmin, but I couldn't find anything that seems to be effective for speeding up.